# Help identifiying button type

Tags: switches, design, identification

I'm building an LED lamp and I want it to have no ON/OFF switches/buttons sticking out from the lamp. 
The switch function I would like to have is like a pushbutton: You push it and it pops out and then you can turn it as a potentiometer and then push it back in.

I have seen the kind of switch I'm describing, but I don't know how it's called.
One example where this kind of swich is used is in Opel Astra radio panel. 
[image: Opel astra radio panel]

Any ideas how is this switch/button called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

An image search for "push-lock potentiometer" will get you half-way there. You'll need to refine it with the on-off switch but I suspect that will make the search results rather less useful.

Note that '-' on most web searches will exclude that term.

Answer (score 0):

it is a `latching push button switch`